# C# arrange the items by matching start and end value

Tags: c#

I have a input in this way,

```
Start= 2, End= 3
Start= 6, End= 7
Start= 3, End= 4
Start= 0, End= 1
Start= 4, End= 5
Start= 1, End= 2
Start= 6, End= 7
```

where I have to display the output that are sorted by their matching start- and end values. The first element are the object whose `Start` doesn't have any matching `End` values, and after that the records(`Start`) have the matching end values.

I needed to have the output in the following ways:

```
Start = 0, End = 1
Start = 1, End = 2
Start = 2, End = 3
Start = 3, End = 4
Start = 4, End = 5
Start = 5, End = 6
Start = 6, End = 7
```

What I have tried so far:

Created a List of `Inputs`

```
var inputs = new List
{
    new Input{Start = 2, End = 3}, 
    new Input{Start = 6, End = 7}, 
    new Input{Start = 3, End = 4}, 
    new Input{Start = 0, End = 1}, 
    new Input{Start = 5, End = 6}, 
    new Input{Start = 4, End = 5}, 
    new Input{Start = 1, End = 2}
};
```

Get the list of all the `Ends`

```
var ends = inputs.Select(t => t.End);
```

Filter from the input where value of `End` matched with the `Start` of the next Objects.

```
var filtered = inputs.Where(t => ends.Any(to => to == t.Start)).ToList();
```

Get the list where `Start` doesn't have the matching ends:

```
var output = inputs.Where(t => !ends.Any(to => to == t.Start)).ToList();
```

Now filter the results as:

```
while (filtered.Count != 0)
{
    var outs = filtered.Where(i => output.Any(l => i.Start == l.End)).FirstOrDefault();
    output.Add(outs);
    filtered.Remove(outs);
}

foreach (Input s in output)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Start = {s.Start}, End = {s.End}");
}
```

[Dotnet fiddle:](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NVja5O)

I have somehow able to solve this problem with this approach. But I have a doubt that this is not a proper ways of solving. Because I have a repetitive filter for getting the matched and unmatched records and, I have also a doubt on the while loop implementation.

Any suggestion for a better approach of solving this problem?

Comment: You've given an _example_ of the output, what actually are the rules for modifying the input to the correct output, in plain English? Off the bat it looks like simply ordering the list by the `Start` property ascending.

Comment: `var ordered = inputs.OrderBy(item => item.Start).ThenBy(item => item.End);`?

Comment: Can you make any assumptions regarding the input? I mean: Is it _guaranteed_ to only contain continuous adjacend elements just out of order? Or may you need to filter out disjoint elements, duplicates ... what about overlaps, includes ?

Comment: @gunr2171 Output are sorted by their matching start- and end values. The problem is not just sorting by Start  property in ascending.

Comment: Yes, but that's inherently true if you just sort by start because your input is like it is. The question is: Can we assume any input will be like this?

Comment: just to simply my question I have a number that could sorted like they are in a ascending order. but as your question @Fildor, no! it is not guaranteed to only contain continuous adjacend elements in order.

Comment: Ah, yes ... now I see. It's in the question. Sorry.

Comment: I think I would approach this with a tree. If you have built it and you have more than one root, then it is not continuous or you have two entries with same end and if on node has a branch-count > 1 then you have duplicates / two entries with same start. Or put otherwise: Your desired result should be a tree with a branch-count of 1 from root to leaf... just as a basic starter. Maybe it would need some more thought to it.

Comment: @Rashik Please state what you want to do (in general, not just an example) at the beginning of the question, before all the code blocks showing what you have tried so far. That makes it much easer to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If the `End` is always equals `Start + 1`. Then, you could take the max value of `Start` and with a simple for loop, you check, if exists, return value, if not, insert the new value.

Here is an extension method that would accept almost all type of collections or arrays :

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Input?> SortAndFill(this IEnumerable<Input?> source)
    {
        if(source == null) yield break; 

        var max = source?.Max(x=> x.Start) ?? 0;

        if (max == 0) yield break;

        max++;

        for (int x = 0; x < max; x++)
        {
            var item = source.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Start == x);

            if (item == null)
                item = new Input(x, x + 1);

            yield return item;
        }

    }

}
```

usage :

```
var result = inputs.SortAndFill().ToArray();
```